# Numerical Integration of $\int_0^1 \log(x) dx$

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

Do you guys have any idea how to handle something like

$\int_0^1 log(x) dx$ numerically in Matlab (I'm only interested in the real part btw)?

I have used Quad, Quadl, "integral" etc all of them find intfy at the origin.

I have tried to change the lower limit to, say 0.00001, and then the result is finite, but 0.00001 is really not good enough and if I use something smaller than 0.00001 the result again is infty.

I should add that the integrand is not a simple log(x) but rather long expression which goes like/(Taylor expansion) log(x) near x=0. I have defined this integrand in a separate function file.

Now $\lim_{x->0} J(x) = -\infty$ where $J$ is the integrand, BUT the integral should be finite at x=0.

Any ideas what to do?

Thanks.

Comment: One thing you can do is find a Gauss quadrature scheme with a weight function of $\log{x}$ over $(0,1)$.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/taylor.html have you taken a look at doing a taylor expansion for $n$ terms where $R_n(x) < \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is your error?

Comment: Thanks for your comment franklin...I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

Probably easiest is to use the closed form result $\int_0^1 \log(x) \mathrm{d}x = -\int_0^\infty t \mathrm{e}^{-t} \mathrm{d}t = -1$, and apply quadratures to $J(x)-\log(x)$:
$$
   \int_0^1 J(x) \mathrm{d}x = -1 +\int_0^1 \left(J(x)-\log(x)\right)\mathrm{d}x
$$

Answer (score 0):

Try open Newton-Cotes methods (simplest, midpoint rule), or gaussian quadrature. These methods does not need to be evaluated at limits of interval.

Answer (score 0):

To numerically compute an integral of the form:

$$I = \int_0^1 \log(x) f(x) dx$$

where $f(x)$ is assumed to be regular at both endpoints, you can go through the formalism of Gaussian quadrature as [explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#General_formula_for_the_weights). You can find the orthogonal polynomials when choosing $\log(x)$ as the weight function using the 3 term recursion relation given at the end of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Gautschi.27s_theorem). The following  quadrature rules can be derived using the methods explained there. If we denote the $n$th order Gaussian quadrature approximation to $I$ as $I_n$, then we have:

$$I_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}w_{n,k}f\left(x_{n,k}\right)$$

the abscissa are given by:

$$
\begin{split}
x_{1,1} &= \frac{1}{4}\\
x_{2,1} &= \frac{1}{42} \left(15-\sqrt{106}\right)\\
x_{2,2} &= \frac{1}{42} \left(15+\sqrt{106}\right)\\
x_{3,1} &= 0.0638907930873254049961166031363\ldots\\
x_{3,2} &= 0.368997063715618765546197645857\ldots\\
x_{3,3} &= 0.766880303938941455423682659817\ldots\\
x_{4,1}&=0.0414484801993832208033213101564\ldots\\
x_{4,2}&=0.245274914320602251939675759523\ldots\\
x_{4,3}&=0.556165453560275837180184354376\ldots\\
x_{4,4}&=0.848982394532985174647849188085\ldots\\
x_{5,1}&=0.0291344721519720533037267621154\ldots\\
x_{5,2}&=0.173977213320897628701139710829\ldots\\
x_{5,3}&=0.411702520284902043174931924646\ldots\\
x_{5,4}&=0.677314174582820380701802667998\ldots\\
x_{5,5}&=0.894771361031008283638886204455\ldots
\end{split}
$$

The weights are:

$$
\begin{split}
w_{1,1} &= -1\\
w_{2,1}&= -\frac{1}{2}-\frac{9}{4 \sqrt{106}}\\
w_{2,2}&= -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9}{4 \sqrt{106}}\\
w_{3,1}&=-0.51340455223236332512930049757\ldots\\
w_{3,2}&=-0.39198004120148755480628718097\ldots\\
w_{3,3}&=-0.09461540656614912006441232147\ldots\\
w_{4,1}&=-0.38346406814513512485004652234\ldots\\
w_{4,2}&=-0.3868753177747626273360082346\ldots\\
w_{4,3}&=-0.1904351269501424153613600145\ldots\\
w_{4,4}&=-0.03922548712995983245258522856\ldots\\
w_{5,1}&=-0.29789347178289445727225787789\ldots\\
w_{5,2}&=-0.3497762265132241803750718703\ldots\\
w_{5,3}&=-0.234488290044052418886906858\ldots\\
w_{5,4}&=-0.098930459516633146976180711\ldots\\
w_{5,5}&=-0.0189115521431957964895826824\ldots
\end{split} 
$$

For example, the difference between $I_5$ for $f(x) = \exp(x)$ and the exact value is approximately $3\times 10^{-13}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just going to throw this into Wolfram for a second...[image]

Ok, now here are some tests..you'll end up with errors other wise..

```
min=1e-10;
max=1;
delta = 1e-2;
x = min:delta:max;
y = @(x) (log(x));
I = trapz(x,y(x))

I =

   -1.0829

min=1e-12;
max=1;
delta = 1e-2;
x = min:delta:max;
y = @(x) (log(x));
I = trapz(x,y(x))

I =

   -1.1059
```

hmmm..

```
min=1e-12;
max=1;
delta = 1e-6;
x = min:delta:max;
y = @(x) (log(x));
I = trapz(x,y(x))
```

fixed...done..

```
I =

   -1.0000
```